# Breaker box or heat pump problem?

Tags: electrical, hvac, heat-pump

We ran our forced air heat pump today.  15 min. in we noticed it just stopped running.  Looking in the breaker panel I could see that the breaker for the heating unit had tripped.  When I tried to reset it, with a very loud bang it tripped the main breaker to the whole panel.  I reset the main breaker, and tried to reset the breaker to the heating unit and it tripped the main breaker again.  I shut the heat pump off and tried a third time, only to trip the main breaker for the whole house again.  What gives?  Panel problem or heat pump problem?

Answer (score 4):

You should contact an Electrician or HVAC technician.  There seems to be a short-circuit somewhere in the circuit supplying the heating unit. **DO NOT** reset the breaker again until the problem is fixed.

The reason I suspect a short-circuit, is because the breakers are reacting so quickly.  If this was an overcurrent situation, the main breaker would likely not trip (unless the panel is severely overloaded).